# Swift: Changing a Parse Object's ACL for a Single User

Tags: swift, parse-platform, acl

I've got an app where one user (current user) grants access to his data to another user. The current user enters the user name of the person he wants to grant access to. Here's my code:

```
var generalInfo = PFObject(className:"ClientData")
generalInfo.objectId = clientIDPassed //This makes sure that I'm changing the right object. 
generalInfo.ACL = PFACL.ACLWithUser(newUserEmail.text) //newUserEmail.text is the text field. Error on this line. 
generalInfo.saveInBackground()
```

Here's the error:

> Cannot invoke "ACLWithUser" with an argument list of type '(String)'

I'm thinking that my problem is that newUserEmail.text is a string, but Parse is looking for a PFUser. Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: By passing a `PFUser` object instead of a `String`.

Comment: @nhgrif how do i convert newUserEmail.text to PFUser? This didn't work: userPF = newUserEmail.text as? PFUser didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know.  Look at some documentation.  I'm assuming you can't just convert a string to a user... that wouldn't make much sense necessarily.

Comment: I'm sorry, my answer was false.. I changed it.
The Installation Table is not accessible from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a PFUser object.

You can login and get the current user by this:

```
var generalInfo = PFObject(className:"ClientData")
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(<#username: String#>, password: <#String#>, block: { (user, error) -> Void in
                    if user != nil && error != nil {
                        // user has logged in
                        generalInfo.objectId = clientIDPassed //This makes sure that I'm changing the right object. 
                        generalInfo.ACL = PFACL.ACLWithUser(user) // user which is passed by the login function.
                        /*
                           In my parse api (v1.7.1) PFACL.ACLWithUser is not available, instead I have to use:
                           PFACL(user: <#PFUser#>)
                        */
                        generalInfo.saveInBackground()
                    } else {
                        // do your error handling
                        println(error!.localizedDescription)   
                    }
                })
```

In other functions and classes you can use `PFUser.currentUser()` to get the logged in user. If the user is not logged in, returns nil

If you want to search for a User you do:

```
var query = PFUser.query()!
query.whereKey("email", equalTo:userNameObject)
query.getFirstObjectInBackground { newUser, error in
  if error == nil {
    println(newUser)
    var userVariable = newUser.objectId as String
  }  
}
```